# Bat file with unknown syntax ("%0" at beginning of path)

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file

I am responsible for a batch file which was created by an employee who left the company without appropriate documentation.

```
@echo off
c:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile %0\..\AddressList.ps1 > %0\..\AddressList.log 2>&1
```

What is the meaning of "%0" at the beginning of each of the two paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%0` is the complete path of the batch file itself, e.g. `C:\Tools\Thing.bat`. (It is very much like $0 in Bash or Perl, or argv[0] in C or Python.)

Together with `..` ("parent directory"), the `%0\..\` causes the filename to be chopped off, and refers to the actual directory that the batch file is in. So for example, if the script is indeed C:\Tools\Thing.bat, then it would be looking for C:\Tools\AddressList.log.

Normally though I would expect `%~dp0\` to be used instead of `%0\..\`. The latter indeed looks a bit weird, as %0 expands to the path of a *file,* not a directory – but *apparently*, in Windows, the `..\` components are handled as a separate processing step, before the real lookup is done (i.e. before the OS determines that it's not a directory), so I guess it works out. On most other operating systems, this trick wouldn't work.